# Struggling with saving data after JSON call

Tags: json, swift, closures, completionhandler

I am trying to save data from a JSON call into a variable (calling this in ViewDidLoad if it makes a difference). I've been stuck on this for quite a while and am getting pretty frustrated.

I know there are topics on this already, but I can't seem to figure it out and I'm hoping theres a simple explanation for what I'm doing wrong.

Edit: The execution goes to "print("breakpoint")" line before doing the JSON call, I'd like to force execution to wait so I can actually fill up wantedCARDSET but am struggling with how to do that. Sorry if that was unclear!

Here's the call in viewDidLoad

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setPickerView.dataSource = self
        setPickerView.delegate = self

        testJSONgrab.getCards(url: "https://mtgjson.com/json/WAR.json") {json, error in

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                for item in json {
                    self.wantedCARDSET.append(item)
                }
            }
        }

        print("breakpoint")
```

getCards function

```
class mtgJSONDATA {
    func getCards(url: String, completionHandler: @escaping ([CARDS], Error?)-> Void) {

        var cardSet = [CARDS]()
        guard let url = URL(string:url) else {return}
        let session = URLSession.shared
        let task = session.dataTask(with: url, completionHandler: {
            (data, response, error) in
            if error == nil {
                guard let data = data else {return}
                do {
                    let decoded = try JSONDecoder().decode(mtgJSON.self, from: data)
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        for item in decoded.cards! {
                            cardSet.append(item)
                        }
                        completionHandler(cardSet, nil)
                    }
                } catch let jsonError {
                    print("Error serializing JSON: ", jsonError)
                }
            }
        })
        task.resume()
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You miss a reload

```
DispatchQueue.main.async { 
   self.wantedCARDSET = item 
   self.setPickerView.reloadAllComponents()
}
```

As the call to get your data is asynchronous